# Swap the product image while hover the product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute, frontend, backend

I am new to Magento 2, and I want to add some creative ideas to my Magento2 site. so I want to add the swap the product images based on their product image role while hovering over the product, I don't know how to implement this idea on my site, can anyone help me to understand the flow of this idea and explain me in the scratch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can apply this reference : https://zemez.io/support/magento/knowledge-base/magento-2-1-x-enable-change-product-image-hover/

Comment: Maybe someone know how to do the same with recently viewed products?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this module for hover image changes:

https://github.com/dmatthew/magento2-hover-image

Answer (score 0):

this module work fine, after add this module in your magento , you want to add role to particular products image is "hover_image" ans select it and save product. after you can show for that product on hover change.

Like this

[image]